# XNA Change Game Service dynamically during runtime

Tags: c#, xna

I have an interface (ICamera) which is implemented by 2 classes (FreeCamera, StaticCamera). The classes are inheriting from GameComponent.

Example definiton:

```
public class FreeCamera : GameComponent, ICamera
{
  ...
}
```

Now I'm adding the classes to the Game Components and register one of the components to a game service

```
private FreeCamera freeCam;
private StaticCamera staticCam;

public Game1()
{
  graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
  Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
  freeCam = new FreeCamera(this) { Enabled = true };
  staticCam = new StaticCamera(this) { Enabled = false };
  Services.AddService(typeof(ICamera, freeCam);
  Components.Add(freeCam);
  Components.Add(staticCam);
  ...
}
```

Then I want to change the provider for the service during the application flow with help of a toggle function

```
namespace Game1
{
  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
    var keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
    if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.C))
    {
      if(freeCam.Enabled)
      {
        Services.RemoveService(typeof(ICamera));
        Services.AddService(typeof(ICamera, staticCam);
        freeCam.Enabled = !freeCam.Enabled;
        staticCam.Enabled = !staticCam.Enabled;
      }
      else
      {
        Services.RemoveService(typeof(ICamera));
        Services.AddService(typeof(ICamera, freeCam);
        freeCam.Enabled = !freeCam.Enabled;
        staticCam.Enabled = !staticCam.Enabled;
      }         
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
  }
}
```

The StaticCamera takes only input by mouse (you can rotate the camera), the FreeCamera can also moved by keyboard input. When I call the method above (by pressing C on the keyboard) the FreeCamera class gets deactivated but the viewport seems frozen and does not react to any input. When I call the method again after a short time the FreeCamera gets activated again and everything works as expected.

Now I have 2 questions regarding this:

- Is it possible to change the service
  provider of a game service in the
  game loop?
- Is there a better approach
  to handle different camera types in a
  game and switch between them easily?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just a quick tip for now: `keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.C) && keyboardLastFrame.IsKeyUp(Keys.C)`

Answer (score 1):

Like you answered, use a camera manager.  It acts as both a factory and a container for the current camera.  The manager you can register as a service.  Manager would look something like this:

```
public class CameraManager
{
    private Dictionary<Type, ICamera> _cameras;
    private ICamera _current;

    public ICamera Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _current;
        }
    }

    // Sets the current cammera to the internal instance of the camera type
    public void SetCurrent<T>() where T : ICamera
    {
        if (!_cameras.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            // TODO: Instantiate a new camera class here...
        }

        _current = _cameras[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

This is just rough code - would need to be filled in more.  One limitation is you can only have one camera per type.  Giving cameras a string name, or an enum flag would let you toggle between an arbitrary number of cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. I just wrote the code down from my head without my IDE at hand, so please do not look too much into syntax errors etc.

In my game I'm using wrapper classes for the input. The code is just a brief example of the problem - how to substitute a game service if both classes are using the same interface.

My new idea: I could use a "manager" class (like CameraManager in this case) which has the following methods

```
public void SetCameraType(CameraType type) //CameraType could be an enum
public ICamera GetCamera()
```

and then put the manager class into the service (with its own interface like ICameraManager).

**Edit:** this was considered as an answer to the comment above ... but it seems I clicked the wrong button - sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think if you left off the code about adding and removing the service in the Update you'd be good and added lines changing the Visible property.  The Enable property effects calls to Update, but the Visible property effects calls to Draw.

So I'd suggest the Update look like this:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
    var keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
    if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.C))
    {
      if(freeCam.Enabled)
      {
        freeCam.Enabled = false;
        freeCam.Visible = false;

        staticCam.Enabled = true;
        staticCam.Visible= true;
      }
      else
      {
        freeCam.Enabled = true;
        freeCam.Visible = true;

        staticCam.Enabled = false;
        staticCam.Visible= false;
      }         
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
  }
```